# When are "winter months" when referring to runway closure?

Tags: chart-supplement, closed-runways

1B9's grass strip is "CLSD WINTER MONTHS", https://www.airnav.com/airport/1B9.

What is the definition of "winter months"? Is it formally Dec 21st through Mar 21st? Or is it just when it's cold outside, for whatever the pilot decides is "cold"?

If it's not NOTAM'ed as closed, is it therefore legally open?

Comment: This seems like a simple "common sense" situation to me. It is a turf strip. It is closed "winter months and after heavy rains." If there is any possibility of there being snow on the ground, or that the turf is waterlogged, you shouldn't land on it...

Comment: My secret decoder ring says that means “we don’t have a snowplow.”

Answer (score 5):

Reviewing the Chart Supplement General Information and Legend pages I cannot find a description of what time period constitutes "Winter Months."

If you think that you may want or need to use the turf/grass runway and you're  uncertain it's available because of the recent weather (or what constitutes "Winter Months" and/or there is not a NOTAM specifying that the runway is closed),  call the airport manager at the phone number listed in the chart supplement (or on the airnav page from your link).

The airport manager should be able to tell you the current status of the turf/grass runway.

Also, if a runway is closed it is often, but not always, marked by a **yellow cross** on each end. See [Airport Markings para. 2-3-6 e. from the AIM](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap2_section_3.html#YI8dcROBE)

Comment: Unsure why this is being downvoted, but I suppose because it's better as a comment than an answer. The advice is sound, though.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a legal butt-cover statement put there by the airport owner to absolve the owner of any liability if someone prangs their plane after it snows, or tries to land when it's soggy and flips over in the mud, and tries to blame the airport operator.

It's a warning that there is no winter maintenance and the place maybe isn't that well drained in spring or after a thunderstorm, so you're on your own.  No calendar date is implied and there is no legal implication from a regulatory standpoint.

Comment: Well, it could also have to do with owner not desiring ruts to be left in the turf!